# Center two images, but keep them in separate row?

Tags: html, css, sass

```
        <div class="client-logo-wrapper">
          <a href="some link"><img class="client-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="client-logo"></a>
          <a href="some link"><img class="contract-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="contract-logo"></a>
        </div>
```

I have these two images in a div. I would like to display underneath another. `display:block` is good for this. However, I would also like to center them. for this, I would like to use flexbox; but then the two images are put *next*  to another, if there is space. But I don't want this to happen. I want them to be on top of one another, yet, centered like this.

How could i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `text-align: center` with `display: block`

```css
a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="client-logo-wrapper">
  <a href="some link"><img class="client-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="client-logo"></a>
  <a href="some link"><img class="contract-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="contract-logo"></a>
</div>
```

But if you want a flexbox solution, use `flex-direction: column; align-items: center;`

```css
.client-logo-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="client-logo-wrapper">
  <a href="some link"><img class="client-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="client-logo"></a>
  <a href="some link"><img class="contract-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="contract-logo"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css-code to achieve what you want:

```
.client-logo-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    }
.client-logo-wrapper img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using flex-box:

```
.client-logo-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.client-logo-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="client-logo-wrapper">
          <a href="some link"><img class="client-logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/1/" alt="client-logo"></a>
          <a href="some link"><img class="contract-logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/2/" alt="contract-logo"></a>
        </div>
```